# code first CTP5 error message

Tags: ef-code-first, ef4-code-only, code-first

I get the following error message with a new project I have set using code first CTP5. Can't find anything on the web about it. Has anyone encountered this error message?

> The context cannot be used while the model is being created.

This occurs the first time my database context is called (code below):

```
using (StaffData context = new StaffData())
{
  return context.Employees.Count(e => e.EmployeeReference) == 1;
}
```

At this point the database has not been created. I have a database initialiser `DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges` which I set in app_start.

Answer (score 1):

I just found out:

This is a bug in CTP5 with self referencing many to many relationships. There is unfortunately no workaround so you will need to remove the relationship until the next release (later this quarter).

Comment: thanks for this answer. I just got it and don't know how to circumvent this problem.